# UniqueVisitors and/or totalCheckins for all places? (Foursquare API)

Tags: api, foursquare

Is there any way to obtain *uniqueVisitors* and/or *totalCheckins* values for a venue I don't manage, for a specified time range?

I would like to get the number of visitors and/or check-ins in last 30 days for certain place, but from what I have been able to find out, these stats are only availible to venue manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, these stats are only available to venue managers.

Comment: So basically there's no way to obtain these values, that's what I've been afraid of. If someone wants to do this or something similar, my solution is to use totalCheckins and createdAt to compute check-ins/day average (not exactly what I wanted, but imho closest possible). Another option would be caching totalCheckins and looking it up again after 30 days, but that's not possible for my app.